# Android save gif from byte array

Tags: java, android, gif

When I am using below code to save a byte array to gif, the gif file is blurred.

But if I save the byte array to a png or jpg is everything OK. Does anybody know what the problem is?

```
public writeToFile(byte[] array) { 
    try { 
        String path = "..."; 
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path); 
        stream.write(array); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIF is limited to 256 colors and do not support real transparency.

[image]

You should use PNG instead of GIF because it offers better compression and features. PNG is great for small and simple images like logos, icons, etc.

JPEG has better compression with complex images like photos.

`png` has a wider color pallete than `gif` and gif is properitary while png is not. gif can do animations, what normal-png cannot. png-transparency is only supported by browser roughly more recent than `IE6`, but there is a Javascript fix for that problem. Both support alpha transparency. In general I would say that you should use png for most webgraphics while using jpeg for photos, screenshots, or similiar because png compression does not work too good on thoose.

Comment: TY for response but the problem is that I am taking data from database which are stored as .gif file.

Comment: But you are right I have converted gif to png in the Android side and the quality of picture is good.